# Log file is not Shrinking on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, shrink, dbcc

I wanted to shrink the log file as much as possible by the command:

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE ('LogFile', 10)
```

and get this error:

> Cannot shrink log file 2 ('LogFile') because the logical log file
>   located at the end of the file is in use.

I tested these solutions, but my problem isn't solved yet

- DBCC OpenTran =>  No active open transactions.
- Change Recovery Model and DBCC ShrinkFile
- Log Backup AND DBCC ShrinkFile

How can I solve this problem?

**SOLVED**

I executed this query

```
SELECT name, database_id, log_reuse_wait, log_reuse_wait_desc FROM sys.databases
```

Result:
log_reuse_wait_desc: CHECKPOINT

and after execute [CHECKPOINT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188748.aspx) and DBCCSHRINKFILE my problem solved.

Comment: What does this show? SELECT name, database_id, log_reuse_wait, log_reuse_wait_desc FROM sys.databases

Comment: log_reuse_wait_desc equal to 'CHECKPOINT'

Comment: Looks like there was some success here. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic122690-24-1.aspx

Comment: I executed CHECKPOINT & DBCC SHRINKFILE, and my problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I executed this query

```
SELECT name, database_id, log_reuse_wait, log_reuse_wait_desc FROM sys.databases
```

Result:
log_reuse_wait_desc: CHECKPOINT

and after execute CHECKPOINT and DBCCSHRINKFILE my problem solved.